# Azure data factory how to use expression builder to create DDL statement

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

```
 {
    "resultSetCount": 1,
    "recordsAffected": 78,
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "rowCount": 78,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "name": "empolyee",
                    "type": "NUMBER(12,0)"
                },
                {
                    "name": "salary",
                    "type": "VARCHAR(16777216)"
                },
                                ]
]
}

}
```

I am excepting Below format output
create or replace TABLE Test_table(
employee NUMBER(12,0),
salary VARCHAR(16777216),
);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Script Activity or Lookup Activity to run DDL commands instead of Expression Builder. Create a database linked service with the required details as shown below:

[image]

Drag the Script Activity into the pipeline, select the created linked service, and enter the script below:

```
create TABLE Test_table(employee int, salary int);
```

Select the query option as shown below:

[image]

This will successfully create the table in the database, as shown below:

[image]